# How to fire keystrokes out of the browser onClick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, macros, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Let's say we have a simple button:

```
 <button type="button" onclick="onClickHandler()">Click Me!</button>
```

How can you do the following on: *onClickHandler()*

1. Switch to a different window, one method i can think of is firing **ALT + TAB**.
2. Do some more key strokes. E.g. type in some message in chat and press ENTER.
3. Switch back to the browser by firing another **ALT + TAB**.

Is it possible? How?

*Edit, To add more details/context to my question:*

What I am trying to achieve here is to make a convenient button on a web page that will auto generate a message based on a template, e.g

> "Hi ${name}, I would like to buy ${item} from your for this ${price}".

This message would then be sent in another active running window, and then the message is typed in (like a macro) and then sent!. After sending, the window focus should still be the Browser.

Comment: why are you using a click handler to bind key events? Question is confusing, please elaborate on expected behaviors

Comment: This is possible in firefox-addon, it involves js-ctypes, which will be OS dependent solution.

Comment: Wait do you want to switch to another browser window? Or another application window? If you want to do another browser window, no need for js-ctypes, you can do that with XPCOM. This is re: firefox-addon.

Comment: Switch to another application. Actually I've found another solution, updating my OP.

Answer (score 0):

**Found my solution**

Instead of javascript doing the hardwork. js will just put the generated string into the clipboard, and fire a keystroke. This keystroke will be detected by AHK (http://ahkscript.org/). And then AHK can do the rest.

Comment: That's nice but ideally you want your extension to not depend on other software. What if users dont have AHK installed? Nice solution thanks for sharing.

Comment: How's that AHK solution working out? Is this going into a firefox addon? I would really avoid that AHK solution, to switch to another application I would use other methods which I could share with you.

Comment: @Noitidart, thanks for the offer. It worked out (but not as good as I wanted), however for copying to clipboard - I resorted to "popping up a prompt dialog and make the user do CTRL+C).

But anyway this was just for a fan-made tool (and open source) for a  game called Path of Exile.
Just to share, I posted the AHK script here:

https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/1164052

Comment: i cant find the script, im more interested in how you launch the AHK script from the browser. Thats cool stuff. :)